# How to write to a text file in a sub directory of program C#?

Tags: c#, filestream, streamwriter

I have been writing a windows forms app for a little bit in c#. I need to write some data to a file that is in a subdirectory of the application's directory. When I create a streamwriter I am getting an exception stating that it cannot create a streamwriter because the file is already open in another process.

I have:

```
StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Application.StartupPath + "@\database\savedStaff.txt");
```

And the Exception I have is this:
"The process cannot access the file.... because it is being used by another process."

I don't have anything other than visual studio that is accessing the directory. I even closed out of source tree I have for version control to make sure that wasn't the issue. Any tips on solving this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How often does this code run? Do you close the writer?

Comment: `@\database\savedStaff.txt` or `@"\database\savedStaff.txt"` ? What's the value of `Application.StartupPath` ?

Comment: As @CodeCaster mentioned there might be another open stream. "using" block might help

Comment: The code executes once on form load and then again on form close. After I am done with the writer I do have both a close and Dispose metod call.

Comment: @user3743446 Show your using block code here. BTW, `StreamWriter` supports relevant paths so you don't actually need the `Application.StartupPath`.

Comment: I don't have a using block. I am just creating an instance and then disposing it when I am done with it in the method,

Answer (score 0):

The error may be misleading. It may be a sharing issue, but it may also be a permissions issue. By default, the Program Files directories, and all subdirectories, require escalation to admin privileges in order to write to them. Just being logged in using an admin account typically isn't enough; you have to explicitly grant the program permission to run as an administrator. This is an anti-malware thing; theoretically, your executables cannot be modified unless you allow it through UAC. I have seen many programs, including my own, report that the file is open by another process, when the real reason Windows refused access was permissions-based.

To get around this, you can:

- Have your program ask for escalation when it runs, so it can do this when necessary. This can be specified in the application manifest.
- Use an installer custom routine to set more relaxed permissions on your subdirectory. I've done this myself for directories containing config files.
- Change the directory being used; common alternatives include the user's AppData/Local folder under an application-specific subfolder, or a subdirectory of "My Documents" (if the file represents a unit of work produced by the program).

Comment: Where does OP mention Program Files? He's running from Visual Studio.